# Importing c code into 32-bit java program

Tags: java, c, 32-bit

I get an error when I do the following steps:

1. Create a dll file of C code by eclipse and mingGW compiler (JDK 32 bit)
2. In Java application, create a header file (JDK 32 bit)
3. Get this dll file and call from a Java project.

But I receive the following error:

> Can't find dependent libraries for (java7 ,8)  Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (Java 6)

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but do you have version 7 or 8 of the JDK installed?

Comment: Looks like the bytecode is generated for Java 6, but you are running Java 7 our 8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)